# Conditional Imports in Swift

Tags: swift, module, swift2

I have a Log function I use in various apps. Its convenient for this to also make Crashlytics logging calls since I use it throughout the app.

However, not every app uses Crashlytics. In Objective C you could handle this with preprocessor conditions.

How would one handle this in code? I think there are ways to make the function conditional perhaps. But how would I optionally or weak import Crashlytics?

```
import Foundation
//import Crashlytics

/// Debug Log: Log useful information while automatically hiding after release.
func DLog<T>(message: T, filename: String = __FILE__, function: String = __FUNCTION__, line: Int = __LINE__) {
//    CLSLogv("\(NSString(string: filename).lastPathComponent).\(function) line \(line) $ \(message)", getVaList([]))
    print("[\(NSString(string: filename).lastPathComponent) \(function) L\(line)] \(message)")
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You can do this now in Swift 4.1 with the new canImport() directive. This is the Swift Evolution proposal that describes how it works: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0075-import-test.md

So you could do:

```
#if canImport(Crashlytics)
func dLog() { 
    // use Crashlytics symbols 
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it a different way in Swift. I would make my log function extensible. I would have an array of log closures that do actual logging and my `dlog` function would invoke all of them e.g.

```
private var logFunctions: [(String) -> ()] = [ { print($0) } ]

func dlog(message: String,  filename: String = __FILE__, function: String = __FUNCTION__, line: Int = __LINE__)
{
    let logMessage = "[\(NSString(string: filename).lastPathComponent) \(function) L\(line)] \(message)"

    for log in logFunctions
    {
        log(logMessage)
    }
}

dlog("Hi", filename: "file", function: "function", line: 1)
print("---")

logFunctions.append{ print("New print: " + $0) }

dlog("Hi", filename: "file", function: "function", line: 2)
```

Output is

```
[file function L1] Hi
--- 
[file function L2] Hi
New print: [file function L2] Hi
```

So in any application that supports Crashlytics, in your application start up code, you add the crashlytics logger to your array of loggers i.e.

```
import Crashlytics // Only needed in the Swift file with app start up code

// ...

logFunctions.append{ CLSLogv($0, getVaList([])) }
```

Of course you should encapsulate all of the above in a class or something.

Comment: Hmm interesting approach for sure.

Comment: @RyanPoolos I think it's vastly superior to trying to emulate the C preprocessor.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible in Swift even though the Swift compiler does not include a preprocessor.

```
import Foundation

#ifdef DEBUG
    import Crashlytics
#endif

/// Debug Log: Log useful information while automatically hiding after release.
func DLog<T>(message: T, filename: String = __FILE__, function: String = __FUNCTION__, line: Int = __LINE__) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
    CLSLogv("\(NSString(string: filename).lastPathComponent).\(function) line \(line) $ \(message)", getVaList([]))
    #else
    print("[\(NSString(string: filename).lastPathComponent) \(function) L\(line)] \(message)")
    #endif
}
```

Now, the following code is untested and MAY need some tweaking - but it can help if you want to clean up your code! @transparent will inline the body of the code, by the way.

```
import Foundation

#ifdef DEBUG
    import Crashlytics
    @transparent printfn(item: String) {
        CLSLogv(item, getVaList([])
    }
#else
    let printfn = println
#endif

/// Debug Log: Log useful information while automatically hiding after release.
func DLog<T>(message: T, filename: String = __FILE__, function: String = __FUNCTION__, line: Int = __LINE__) {
    printfn("\(NSString(string: filename).lastPathComponent).\(function) line \(line) $ \(message)")
}
```

Please note: you must set the "DEBUG" symbol as it is not predefined. Set it in the "Swift compiler - Custom Flags" section of the compiler, "Other Swift Flags" line. You cand efine the DEBUG symbol with the -D DEBUG entry.
Hope I was able to help!

Comment: a debug flag does not solve my problem. I need to check for the existence of Crashlytics. Not debug.

Comment: Ryan, you can replace DEBUG with any other variable just as long as you define it in the compiler flags section.

Comment: #ifdef has been replaced with #if https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID34